# Kivy Android Scikitlearn

Tags: android, scikit-learn, kivy

I'm trying to build a test Android application based on Kivy and Scikitlearn. To build the apk I use buildozer. The code of the app is the basic Hello world example. In the buildozer.spec file I add scikit-learn as an external library:

```
[app]

title = MyTest

package.name = kivycrash2

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

version = 0.1

requirements =  kivy, numpy, scikit-learn

orientation = landscape
```

When I try to build the apk, I get following error:

```
 ImportError: Numerical Python (NumPy) is not installed.
    scikit-learn requires NumPy >= 1.6.1.
```

I have also tried to put sklearn instead of scikit-learn with no success. Is it possible to satisfy the Numpy required version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that scikit-learn is searching for a numpy installation during its own setup, but it doesn't know to look in the android build directory where numpy has been built for the android architecture. I'd try creating a python-for-android recipe for scikit-learn (rather than your current method which tries to use pip) that either patches it to override the numpy check, or possibly tries to let it detect numpy correctly by adding the right directory to the PYTHONPATH - but I'm not sure if that would work, it depends on what it tries to import during installation.

There are also other possibilities, e.g. the new python-for-android toolchain possibly has a way to let setup.py find numpy automatically, but this doubles the numpy build time and still requires that you make a recipe.